# How tangent distance works in three-dimentional space

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, distance

I've read about tangent distance used in machine learning but I don't really know how it works. Concretely, consider two very different manifolds **M1** and **M2** and two points **x1**, **x2** on that two manifolds respectively. **M1** is very far from **M2**. What if the tangent plane **p1** of **M1** at **x1** isn't parallel to the tangent plane **p2** of **M2** at **x2** ? In fact, **p1** will intersect **p2** in this case, so distance(**x1**, **x2**) is zero. This means that **x1** and **x2** will be classied into the same class regardless to the fact that **M1** is very far from **M2**. Can anybody explain this paradox for me ? Thanks alot for your helps

Comment: " In fact, p1 will intersect p2 in this case" - why?

Comment: sorry, I've got some typing mistake, I've fixed it